# Generate two sequences of numbers separated by "|"

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, seq

I'm using bash (CentOS 5) and looking to generate this output (I
assume I could use `seq` or `echo` together maybe?):

```
1|1,
2|2,
3|3,
....
31|31,
32|32,
33|33,
```

I googled `seq` examples for over two hours and the closest I can come up with is:

```
echo {1..31}..{1..31} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

which almost gives me what I want, but messes up when I change the .. to | or even "|").

A second number generation I need is formatted the same way but for
descending years, i.e.:

```
2015|2015,
2014|2014,
...
1938|1938,
1937|1937,
1936|1936,
```

I've already manually typed out these two lists, but I would love any
input on how I could have done this from the command line for future
needs and to learn (`seq` or `echo`, I'm assuming).

Comment: Is the comma at the end of each line part of the output you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
seq 0 31 | awk '{ print $1"|"$1", " }'
```

in the descending case:

```
seq 31 -1 0 | awk '{ print $1"|"$1", " }'
```

These use awk to duplicate the number on each line, separated by a
pipe character.

Or using pure bash (as suggested by DopeGhoti in a comment):

```
for n in {0..31}; do printf "%d|%d,\n" $n $n; done
for n in {31..0}; do printf "%d|%d,\n" $n $n; done
```

Comment: Why fork out to two binaries?  `for i in {0..31}; do echo "$i|$i,"; done`.

Comment: There's more than one way to do it, for sure. I'll edit my answers to add more solutions.

Comment: It's `bash`, there's always more than one way to do it (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti  - why *not* fork two *tiny* binaries that do the job *much faster* than the slow, monolithic shell - which can only do it with *two* for loops - one which generates the set internally, and the second which then iterates over it in the script. `for ... {num..num}` is an ugly way to do anything.

Answer (score 10):

My twists:

- pure `awk`

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{for(;n<31;)print ++n"|"n","}'
  ```
- `printf` + `xargs`

  ```
  printf '%s\n' {0..31} | xargs -I {} echo "{}|{},"
  ```
- `repeat` loop in `zsh`

  ```
  n=0; repeat 32 echo "$n|$((n++)),"
  ```

Answer (score 7):

```
seq 100|sed 's/.*/&|&,/'
```

...should do it fine...

With just a shell:

```
i=-1 x=31
while [ "$i" -lt "$x" ]
do    echo "$((i+=1))|$i,"
done
```

Comment: Awesome!  thank you very much this does exactly what im looking for.. now im going to hit the man pages and see how.

Answer (score 7):

And for fun with `paste`:

```
paste -d'|,' <(seq 31) <(seq 31) /dev/null
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution (in ksh93, bash, zsh):

```
printf '%s|%s,\n' {1..31}{,}             ### Ascending  sequence.
printf '%s|%s,\n' {2015..1936}{,}        ### Descending sequence.
```

Or, if you must use a loop:

```
i=0 x=31
while    (( i++ < x ))
do       echo "$i|$i,"
done
```

Comment: Clever use of `{,}`, really nice!

Answer (score 5):

Some convoluted ones:

```
seq  -f %.0f 0.9 0.5 33.8 | paste -d '|,\n' - - /dev/null
seq  -f %.0f 2015.1 -0.5 1935.2 | paste -sd '|,\n' - - /dev/null
```

Note that `seq` is not a standard command. POSIXly, if you want to print a sequence a number, the best tools are `awk` and `bc`. `bc` can do arbitrary precision arithmetic but is very limited when it comes to format its output, so `awk` is a more obvious solution here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=33;i++) print i "|" i ","}'
```

Though you could use `bc` like:

```
echo 'for (i=1;i<=33;i++) {i;i}' | bc | paste -d '|,\n' - - /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

Using perl you may do both the `seq` loop and the `print` formatting in a single process:

```
perl -e 'for (1..31) {print "$_|$_,\n"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't strictly answer the "from the command line" part, but since you say you manually typed out the lists, allow me to present: **The Easy and Fast Way** to type out your lists, using `vim`.

---

**The Long Version**

Open up `vim` by typing: `vim` at the command line.

Enter insert mode by pressing `i`.  Type the first line: `1|1,` and press `<Esc>` to exit insert mode.

Press `q` to begin recording a macro, and press `x` (arbitrarily) to record the macro into register "x".

Type `yy` to copy the current line and `p` to paste it.  This will also put your cursor at the beginning of the newly pasted line.  Then, type `<C-a>` (Control-A) to increment the number under the cursor.

Type `t,` to move your cursor forward to just before the next comma (which puts it on the second number on the line).  Type `<C-a>` again to increment this number also.

Type `q` to stop recording the macro.

Now all that remains is to play back the macro as many times as you want.  We'll say 15, just for demonstration.  Type `15@x` and your macro will be replayed 15 times, so your screen will now show your list from 1 to 17.  Then if you want more lines, you can just type, for instance, `500@x`.

If you have too many lines, type the letter `k` to move up in the file and `j` to go down.  When you are on the first line to be deleted, you can delete from there to the end of the file by typing `dG`.

---

**The Short Version**

To generate the list from 1 to 31, open `vim` by typing `vim<Enter>` at the command prompt, then press the following keys:

`i1|1,<Esc>qxyyp<C-a>t,<C-a>q29@x`

---

I'm fully familiar with `seq`, `tr`, `echo` and I understand the various other answers that have been posted.  It's my considered opinion that the best tool for this job is `vim`, unless you actually need to *script* the text generation.